# Is there such a genre where the main gameplay focuses on writing bots?

Tags: terminology

What is the name of the genre of game where you don't actually play, but rather you program your own player, using, e.g. a scripting language?

I'm not asking for a list. I'm asking for the terminology used for these games. I'm struggling to find one example in Google, which I blame to my lack of right keywords.

Comment: Check out the King of the Hill tag on Code Golf SE: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill

Comment: are you asking about [programming based games](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952/best-programming-based-games)?

Comment: It sounds accurate.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_game

Answer (score 3):

These games are referred to as Programming Games or Programming Based Game. Some of these games include Robocode and Robowar. If you are into programming, you should check out StackOverflow, another QnA on StackExchange.